# How does Entity Framework track updates?

Tags: entity-framework

Inserts and Deletes are easy - they have dedicated methods. But what does it do to detect changes to loaded records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many articles describing the change tracking mechanism.

[Tracking Changes in POCO Entities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456848.aspx)

[Identity Resolution, State Management, and Change Tracking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896269.aspx)

Comment: Oh, I see now - when you create or load objects, these are proxies. What I still do not understand, is how these proxies mimic "real" POCO's so well.